# Proguard NoSuchMethodError ITelephony

Tags: android, proguard

My code works fine but after applying proguard i am getting the following exception

> 05-04 16:12:00.803: E/AndroidRuntime(22257):
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony.a

I ma having `Itelephony.aidl` but still getting the error. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to around this ?

On google, i couldn't get more information on examples of how to keep interfaces, interface members and inner classes along with inner class members.

Actually i want to keep everything in my app but just obsfucate and optimize it. Is there a way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to exclude the `ITelephony` class from *proguard*, i.e. add this ...

```
-keep class com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony { *; }
```

... entry to your `proguard.cfg` file. You'll find it in your project root folder.

*[Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)* is a tool that obfuscates your code, i.e. makes it more compact and less readable for others by applying various optimization (e.g. renaming classes). So in some cases this might have a negative impact on the functionality, e.g. if you consider dynamic reflection calls.

Cheers!